# Drupal 7 - How do I use pathauto taxonomy terms in views arguments

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have been banging my head against this problem all day. I'm using Drupal 7, and I'm trying to create a contextual filter that uses the pathauto string for a taxonomy term, not the taxonomy term ID.

So, I can make this work:

http://foobar.com/tags/1

But not:

http://foobar.com/tags/tagname

I have created a contextual filter of 'Content: has taxonomy term ID'. I have turned on the default taxonomy view and modified the path in it to try to create a URL that will work. I have gone into /admin/config/search/path/patterns and modified the taxonomy term path. As a result I can make the numeric ID appear in almost any URL with any prefacing text, but I can't get my view to use the pathauto-generated string for a taxonomy term instead of the taxonomy ID.

Any ideas? Am I missing something? All help is appreciated.

--Marshall

Answer (score 0):

The default view "Taxonomy term," is using a contextual filter very similar to what you are trying to achieve, so possibly this could assist you in how to set something like this up.  I would try creating a view of type taxonomy instead of content though.